Laravel get latest model for each model and group count totals
I'm trying to show a count for each subscription status for my client model in my Laravel project. A client can have many subscription status entries, but I only care about the newest entry of each. my relationship cientSubscriptionStatusLatest takes care of this. There are many statuses.
I only care about returning the appropriate status and a count for each status, when I try to perform this query, I keep bumping into the same error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bume_db_ryan.client_subscription_status.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (Connection: mysql, SQL: select client_id, status, COUNT(status) AS total_rows from client_subscription_status where client_subscription_status.client_id in (4, 5) group by client_id, status order by created_at desc, id desc)

What am I missing?
$clients = Client::with([
    'clientSubscriptionStatusLatest' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(
            'client_id',
            'status',
            DB::raw("COUNT(status) AS total_rows")
        )->groupBy('client_id', 'status');
    }
])->leftJoin('client_subscription_status', 'clients.id', '=', 'client_subscription_status.client_id')
->select('client_subscription_status.status', 'clients.id')
->orderBy('clients.id', 'desc')
->get();

I'm looking to get a response back identical to:
[{
    'status' => 1,
    'total_rows' => 1000,
    'created_at' => '2024-01-01 00:00:00'
}, {
    'status' => 2,
    'total_rows' => 500,
    'created_at' => '2024-01-02 00:00:00'
}]


You can't order by created_at because that isn't a grouped column, so there's nothing to order. And you haven't included created_at in the selected fields either as far as I can see, so that is obviously not going to give you the created_at field in the output, as per your sample expected response.

Thanks. What would I need to achieve the desired result?

Isn't SELECT client_id, status, COUNT(*) AS total_rows, MAX(created_at) as created_at FROM client_subscription_status GROUP BY client_id, status what you want?

Running that query gives me some rows where client_id is the same, but the status is different. This isn't right because I only want the newest status for each client_id

That sounds like a "groupwise-max" problem.
